# How to block UI in IPhone

Tags: iphone, user-interface, freeze

How can I block UI thread without using sleep?

Just to be clear: I understand that UI will freeze for user, but that is the idea.

Can I run empty RunLoops? Any other ways.

Comment: do you want to block thread or just disable user interaction with UI?

Comment: I would say block
but disable may also work...so..how can I disable UI (all buttons, tabs and so on)?

thank you

Comment: InteractionEnabled to NO set on root view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to block all interaction with your UI, call the `UIApplication` method `-beginIgnoringInteractionEvents`. If you're actually trying to prevent the entire UI from doing anything (which is not a good idea—your application might block the appearance of a system notification, for instance), then yes, an `NSRunLoop` would probably be the right approach.

Comment: yes, this is ok. But just for example: how to block everything with RunLoop?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with run loops, but I think starting one with -run or -runUntilDate: would do that.